# jQuery and JSON Push error

Tags: jquery, json

I am working on the GUI for a web app and they want me to use json to get values. I have a simple script to pull the value of a key, but it's not working.

HTML

```
<div class="get-data">
  <p>Get Data</p>
  <div class="json"> 
      <!--<p> will be created here --> 
  </div>
</div>
```

JSON

```
 [
     {
        "id":-596859137166526783,
        "avatarDefinitionId":2,
        "tenantId":1,
        "avatarName":"qln320",
        "attributes":{
             "qln320.set.media.handling":"TEAR_OFF",
             "qln320.snr.memory.free":"66939392",
      }
     }
 ]
```

jQuery

```
 $.getJSON('json/test.json', function(data) {
 var items = [];

 data[0].attributes['qln320.snr.memory.free'];

 $('<p/>', {
   'class': 'raw-list',
   html: items.join('')
   }).appendTo('.json');
 });
```

Comment: Do you have a line number in the error message? Where does it point to? I don't find any attempt to access `a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through `attributes` object, `val` in your code returns value of `qln320.set.media.handling` and `qln320.snr.memory.free` properties, in fact it returns `"TEAR_OFF"` and `"66939392"`, but you are pushing hard-coded `val.qln320.snr.memory.free` strings regardless of the returned values.

```
$.each(data[0].attributes, function (key, val) {
    items.push(val);
});

$('<p/>', {
    'class': 'raw-list',
    html: items.join('')
}).appendTo('.json');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XDZ8Y/

However the error, `[TypeError: a is undefined]` is not be related to the posted script.

Comment: That fixed the error, thanks!!! I notice that returns the entire array though. If you look at my above code, what if I only want to grab the value of 1 of the keys. I tried inserting my push val.qln320.dyn.prop.location to your code but it doesnt work.

Comment: @ndesign11 In that case you don't need to use `$.each`, you can code: `data[0].attributes['qln320.snr.memory.free'];`

Comment: I don't understand. If I use $(data[0].attributes['qln320.snr.memory.free']; I get errors.

Comment: I removed my for .each and the $ now it's only data[0].attributes['qln320.snr.memory.free']; but there are no errors and I don't see "TEAR_OFF" in the DOM

Comment: @ndesign11 Are you still using `push` method? try setting the html of the `p` element as     `html: data[0].attributes['qln320.snr.memory.free']` or `data.attributes['qln320.snr.memory.free']`.

Comment: I updated my new code in the main posting. I tried both data[0].attributes['qln320.snr.memory.free'] and data.attributes['qln320.snr.memory.free']. Neither seem to return "TEAR_OFF". I also tried it using your fiddle but still doesnt seem to work

Comment: I must of misunderstood your final suggestion. Works like a charm, Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If that is the exact json code, then it is inside an array, you need to modify your code this way,

```
$.getJSON('json/test.json', function(data) {
 var items = [];
if(data.length)
{
var data=data[0];
```

//rest of your code.